# How to debug doPost()

Tags: wordpress, debugging, google-apps-script, post

I am using these simple functions to test and learn to deploy App Script as a web app.

```
function doPost(request){
   var parameters = request.parameters;
   console.log(parameters);
   return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(JSON.stringify(parameters));
}

function doGet(e){
  var parameters = e.parameters;
  console.log(parameters);
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(JSON.stringify(parameters));
}
```

In the Executions tab, I can see `doGet` execution's log, however, for `doPost` the execution is not clickable.
[image]
How can I debug `doPost` function then? Currently I just want to see if I have properly built the POST request body from a wordpress site.

```
$admins = [1,7,29,30,35,40];
$api_url = "https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbwIdr66o2Cgp7Z09mUQrEkc5RtgenKfgZTCbCnALb7PfESk7odCPqHIWehFEEjqOPtj1g/exec";
$response = wp_remote_post($api_url, array(
  'method' => 'POST',
  'body' => json_encode($admins),
));

if ( is_wp_error( $response ) ) {
  $error_message = $response->get_error_message();
  // Handle the error appropriately
} else {
  $response_body = wp_remote_retrieve_body( $response );
  // Handle the response body appropriately
}
dump($response_body);
```

The $response_body is a HTML document instead of a JSON string as I'd expected.

I know it is probably because I used `HtmlService.createHtmlOutput` in the `doPost` function, but this is not the point, the point is how can I debug doPost function if some more complex errors occur.

Comment: You need to link it to a google cloud project and use that logger... Or you just write the content to a json file to you're drive? Or use [reqbin](https://reqbin.com/) to catch the json and check it there.

Comment: I've chekced the steps to link it to a google cloud project, it is a little complicated for me. Especially because I am using a managed organization account, when I go to the log explorer screen, it says permission denied and I need to check IAM permission or talk to the admin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you're supposed to use [Cloud Logging](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/logging#cloud_logging). According to Google, this is intended because the Apps Script Execution logs do not show interactions that were not made from a browser. You can find a thread in their [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/258991492) explaining this.

If you cannot attach a [standard GCP project](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/cloud-platform-projects) to use Cloud Logging due to permissions, then  as a simple workaround you can write the POST data somewhere else, like a spreadsheet:

```js
function doPost(e) {
  postToSheet(e.postData.contents)
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput("Some Output")
}

function postToSheet(data){
  var sheetid = "<Your sheet ID>"
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sheetid)
  ss.getRange("A1").setValue(data)
}
```

You could also consider to use [UrlFetchApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app) to POST the data back to your WP app.

Also do note that in your sample you're trying to read `request.parameters` for POST data, but `parameters` refers to the URL query string. To [read the POST body](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web#request_parameters) you have to use `e.postData.contents`.